# CSS Grid structure

Tags: css, templates, flexbox, css-grid

I have some problem for making grid for template
[image]

I need to make such grid, and it's not a problem if I can do 3 columns - but I cant... On mobile it have order
block3
block1
block4
block2
block5
How can I do this? I trued grid-template-area with 2 rows, like
grid-template-areas:
"block1 block3 block5"
"block2 block4 block5";
But it's not working, because block3 more smaller then block1...
I would be very grateful for any help

Added code. Included mobile version

codepen.io/PAKOT/pen/VwzLNJb

I need center block in grid area to be close to top block (green and yellow together in 1 column)
P.S. Seems I found, if smbd would need in future
grid-template-areas:
"block1 block3 block5"
"block1 block4 block5"
"block2 block4 block5";

Comment: Please show us the CSS you tried for mobile, is it in a media query? And also please show what layout you want on narrower devices.

Comment: added code https://codepen.io/PAKOT/pen/VwzLNJb

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```css
* {
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#col1 {
 width: 20%;
}

.smallBox {
  width: 90%;
  height: 45%;
  background: orange;
}

#col2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.topBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background: orange;
}

.bigBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65%;
  background: orange;
}

#col3 {
  width: 30%;
}

.tallBox {
  width: 90%;
  height: 93%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
  <div id="col1" class="columns">
    <div class="smallBox"></div>
    <div class="smallBox"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="col2" class="columns">
    <div class="topBox"></div>
    <div class="bigBox"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="col3" class="columns">
    <div class="tallBox"></div>
  </div>
```

using flexbox